# Export raster based on attribute table value in R

Tags: r, attributes, raster

I have a large raster file that has an associated raster attribute table (RAT):

```
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 32550, 13900, 452445000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent      : 0, 13900, 0, 32550  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : NA 
data source : H:\My Drive\raster.grd 
names       : mr200_2012 
values      : -318, 151078  (min, max)
attributes  :

ID COUNT  Value_of_interest 
1   4        45
2   7        1
3   94       5
4   5        7
...
```

The raster displays on the values, from -318 to 151078. I want to be able to export a raster with one of the attribute values as the 'value'. 
For example changing the 'value' to the 'Value_of_interest' So that the raster displays a (min,max) of 1 to 45.

This is very similar to how the [Lookup](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/lookup.htm) tool works in ArcMap. I am just looking for a programmatic way to do this.

I have not worked with RAT that much and am unfamiliar with some of the functionality of it. I have tried using a `data.table` and `data.frame` approach but the resultant table is really big and most times won't generate due to size. My thought was that I could create a `data.frame` with `xy` coordinates and then change the `z` value to the 'Value_of_interest'.

I think this will be sufficient reproducible data:

```
xy <- matrix(rnorm(200),20,20)
xy<-raster(xy)
xy
rat<-data.frame("ID" = runif(10,0,10),
            "b" = runif(10,0,10),
            "variable of interest" = runif(10,10,20))


levels(xy)[[1]]<-rat
```

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution to this problem. Using the `deratify` function you can seperate out certain attributes and create new single band rasters.

```
New.raster <- deratify(Raster.with.attributes, "Some_Column_in_raster")
```

New raster will be single band with values of the column specified.