# Equivalent of raster::deratify in terra r package

Tags: r, r-raster, terra

I have a raster with a raster attribute table (RAT). I want to generate a new raster using one of the column values of the raster attribute table. It can be done using `raster::deratify` as described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51756200/export-raster-based-on-attribute-table-value-in-r). I am giving a simple example from `raster` package

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(nrow=10, ncol=10)
values(r) = 1
r[51:100] = 2
r[3:6, 1:5] = 3
r <- ratify(r)
rat <- levels(r)[[1]]
rat$landcover <- c("Pine", "Oak", "Meadow")
rat$code <- c(0.002,0.0056,0.0124)
levels(r) <- rat
r
# extract values for some cells
i <- extract(r, c(1, 2, 25, 100))
i
# get the attribute values for these cells
factorValues(r, i)

# create a single-layer raster using the code of RAT
x <- deratify(r, "code")

extract(x, c(1, 2, 25, 100))
```

How can it be achieved in `terra` R package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a SpatRaster from your example RasterLayer

```
library(terra)
x <- rast(r)
x
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 10, 10, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 36, 18  (x, y)
#extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#source(s)   : memory
#categories  : landcover, code 
#name        :  layer 
#min value   :   Pine 
#max value   : Meadow
```

"code" is the second category, so you can do

```
y <- as.numeric(x, 2)
y
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 10, 10, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 36, 18  (x, y)
#extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#source(s)   : memory
#name        :   code 
#min value   : 0.0020 
#max value   : 0.0124
```

Comment: Suppose, I have only `1, 2, 3` in raster `r`, now how can I add  `c("Pine", "Oak", "Meadow")` and `c(0.002,0.0056,0.0124)` to `r` raster using `terra` r package?

Comment: See `?terra::levels`

Comment: I have raised a new question. Can you please visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76026449/addition-of-attribute-data-to-classified-raster-giving-weird-results-in-terra-r/76026609?noredirect=1#comment134085793_76026609)?