# Addition of attribute data to classified raster giving weird results in terra R

Tags: r, terra

I have a raster data that I have classified into 3 classes. Then I want to add values to each class. I am using the following code

```
library(terra)

f <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra") 
r <- rast(f)

# classify the values into three groups
m <- c(min(global(r, "min", na.rm=TRUE)), 275, 1,
       275, 410, 2,
       410, max(global(r, "max", na.rm=TRUE)), 3)

#Reclassify the raster stack
rclmat <- matrix(m, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)
rc <- classify(r, rclmat, include.lowest=TRUE)
plot(rc)

#Add some values to raster attribute table
rc$code <- c(0.002, 0.0056, 0.0124)

#Generate raster using the new column
y <- as.numeric(rc, 2)
plot(y)
```

[image]

As you can see the second plot is weird. How can I rectify it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example data

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra") )
m <- c(-Inf, 275, 1,
           275, 410, 2,
           410, Inf, 3)
rclmat <- matrix(m, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)
rc <- classify(r, rclmat, include.lowest=TRUE)
```

To assign attributes, you must use `levels(x)<-`  (see `?levels`). You use `$<-` but that creates a new layer.

```
levels(rc) <- data.frame(ID=1:3, code=c(0.002, 0.0056, 0.0124))
rc
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 90, 95, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
#extent      : 5.741667, 6.533333, 49.44167, 50.19167  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
#source(s)   : memory
#categories  : code 
#name        :   code 
#min value   :  0.002 
#max value   : 0.0124
```

If you now wanted to put the "code" values in the cells, you could  proceed with

```
y <- as.numeric(rc, 1)
```

(it should be 1 rather than 2 as you only have one category.)

You could also do that with

```
rc <- classify(r, rclmat, include.lowest=TRUE)
s <- subst(rc, 1:3, c(0.002, 0.0056, 0.0124))
```

ut if that is the output you want, you should use these values in `classify`, so that you can do this in one step.

```
m <- c(-Inf, 275, 0.002,  
        275, 410, 0.0056,
        410, Inf, 0.0124)

rclmat <- matrix(m, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)
rc <- classify(r, rclmat, include.lowest=TRUE)
```

Note that you can further simplify your *original* (not the one above) call to `classify`:

```
rc <- classify(r, c(-Inf, 275, 410, Inf), include.lowest=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be that the classes in the attribute table do not match the range of values in the raster (after adding new values).  We could maintain the match by first calculating the class intervals for continuous numerical variables with the `classIntervals()` function from the `classInt` package, and then assigning values to each class.

```
library(terra)
library(classInt)

f <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra") 
r <- rast(f)

# classify the values into three groups
m <- c(min(global(r, "min", na.rm=TRUE)), 275, 1,
       275, 410, 2,
       410, max(global(r, "max", na.rm=TRUE)), 3)

#Reclassify the raster stack
rclmat <- matrix(m, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)
rc <- classify(r, rclmat, include.lowest=TRUE)
plot(rc)

# calculate class breaks/intervals 
brks <- classIntervals(values(rc), n=3, style="jenks")$brks

# assign values to classes based on class breaks/intervals
rc$code <- ifelse(values(rc) <= brks[2], 0.002,
                  ifelse(values(rc) <= brks[3], 0.0056, 0.0124))

#Generate raster using the new column
y <- as.numeric(rc, 2)
plot(y)
```

[image]

Here is an extension to show how we could tweak changing the `brks[]`:

```
library(terra)
library(classInt)

f <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra") 
r <- rast(f)

# classify the values into three groups
m <- c(min(global(r, "min", na.rm=TRUE)), 275, 1,
       275, 410, 2,
       410, max(global(r, "max", na.rm=TRUE)), 3)

#Reclassify the raster stack
rclmat <- matrix(m, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)
rc <- classify(r, rclmat, include.lowest=TRUE)
plot(rc)

# calculate class breaks/intervals 
brks <- classIntervals(values(rc), n=3, style="jenks")$brks

# assign values to classes based on class breaks/intervals
rc$code <- ifelse(values(rc) <= brks[3], 0.002,
                  ifelse(values(rc) <= brks[1], 0.0056, 0.0124))

#Generate raster using the new column
y <- as.numeric(rc, 2)
plot(y)
```

[image]

Comment: When you are using `classIntervals` on reclassified raster, it is changing the class boundaries.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the feedback. So it is possible that the class boundaries may be changing, depending on the specific reclassification rules that you are using. But this is clearly beyond my knowledge. Good luck!